# get three-letter day name from date command

Tags: command-line, date

```
date +%b
```

gives me the three-letter abbreviation of the current month name (I found that out online, it's not in my `man date` nor can I find the answer to this question in my `man date`).

How do I get the current day name? e.g. Sun, Mon, Tue, etc. ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [`man date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html):

```
%a     locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Sun)
```

Comment: oh that's not in my `man date` but it works. When I search `abbr` in my man page it just shows `yy` and `cc`

Comment: FWIW you might see the full list detailed in the man page for `strftime`, the system call which `date` makes use of.

Comment: @steve oh cool, thank you. Indeed `%a    is replaced by national representation of the abbreviated weekday name.` is in my `man strftime`

Comment: To be pedantic, strftime is a library call (in section 3 of the manual) not a system call.